Why instects aren't blinded by Sun?
Insects have compound eyes with very wide field of view, but when they're in sunlight some of ommatidium would be directly facing the Sun. Doesn't that damage photoreceptors?

Why do you think insect eyes are not damaged by sunlight?

@BryanKrause that is not an answer to my question. I don't know, if I knew the answer I wouldn't be asking a question, they cannot blink so they need to look at Sun. And if they go partially blind then what's the point of having compound eye looking almost everywhere when half of it will be useless later

It doesn't make much sense to ask a why question unless you have evidence that the thing you're asking why actually happens. How can anyone answer "why" for something that isn't true?

@BryanKrause So they go blind? Then why they have initially such wide range of view if insects are gonna be partially blinded

Their photoreceptors are going to be damaged if exposed to enough UV light, yes. I think you're making poor estimates of how much a given receptor is actually pointed directly at the sun, though. Also remember that most insects live short lives.

Your question interested me, I've posted: Does the Ogre-Faced Spider regenerate part of it's eyes daily? which I thought might interest you.
